# Printing the SUM of numbers in a random list in a GUI

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I am making a lotto number generator system (using TKinter and a GUI), I am trying to make a SUM for all the random numbers generated but I can't quite figure out how to print the SUM of the numbers within the button.

Ideally what I would like is for someone to press SUM and then it would SUM the numbers and 'print' it somewhere in the GUI.

This is the Code that I have for the Button so far:

```
Button(window, text="GO", width=6, command=start).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
Button(window, text="CLEAR", width=6, command=clear).grid(row=1, column=10, columnspan=2)
Button(window, text="SUM = ",print(sum[numbers]), width=6).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Do tell me if what I have put is not enough!

Cheers

Comment: you don't "print" the sum of numbers into the button, you put it into the text string.  like `text = "SUM = "+str(sum(numbers))` or equivelent.

Comment: The answer is what Tadhg said, but you should use a different widget (label is more suitable) to display the result

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers. How can I make a label?